# Is it possible to solve this problem with Regular Expression?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to divide long text in small parts, so that every part is at least N characters and ended with some of the stop punctuation marks (? . !). If the part is bigger than N characters we sttoped when the next punctuation mark appear.

For example :

Lets say `N = 10`

```
Do you want lime? Yes. I love when I drink tequila.
```

This sentence should be divided in two parts.

```
[1] Do you want lime?
[2] Yes. I love when I drink tequila.
```

Comment: Are you using java, javascript, php? In any case, it can be done (with efforts).... :-)

Comment: I'm trying to do this in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this? (Thanks to KennyTM for final optimizations.)

```
.{10}[^.?!]*[.?!]+
```

Comment: No need to escape these characters inside character classes. And this regex will always match the entire string.

Comment: You're right, there was a problem. The escaping doesn't hurt, I believe.

Comment: I also try this: prog = re.compile('/([^\.\?\!]{10,}[^\.\?\!]*?[\.\?\!]+)+/')
result = prog.split(test). But the result was whole sentence from the example.

Comment: @Ilija: I think you want to use prog.findAll() instead of prog.split(). I've updated the regex for use in Python.

Comment: You could use `{10}` as a short cut of `{10,10}`. Also, I think `[^.?!]*` don't need to be lazy any more.

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes to the shortcut. The expression evolved over time, so this small improvement was overlooked. ;) The [^.?!]*? is absolutely necessary (unless I'm missing something) to switch to non-greedy matching. Otherwise it would just match all of: 'Hello, this is part 1. And this should be part 2.', instead of matching only part 1 and part 2 in distinct matches. It depends on Python's default setting for greediness, of course.

Comment: @Thomas: No it won't match all of them. Notice that it is `[^.?!]*` not `.*`.

Comment: @KennyTM: Haha, darn, got lost in my own expression. You're absolutely right. With that change, it should be as concise as it gets, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

```
.{10,}?[.!?]+\s*
```

should work. It will also keep repeated punctuation characters together, so it splits `Do you want lime??? Yes. I love when I drink tequila.` into `Do you want lime???` and `Yes. I love when I drink tequila.`

However, it doesn't take quoted speech into account and will break `Peter said "Hi! How about dinner tonight?" and left.` into `Peter said "Hi!`,  `How about dinner tonight?` and `" and left.`

Could that be a problem that needs to be taken into account?

Comment: No, that doesn't need to be taken into account? Now, I'm testing,

Comment: How would it split: Hello ?? !! ... My name is not important.So I'm not saying it ...

Comment: I'm trying this in Python prog = re.compile('.{10,}?[.!?]+\s*')
result = prog.split(test) but it gives me emtpy list

Comment: @Thomas: Then it should probably be .{10,}?[.!?][\s.!?]*